# Gaps between variable and text PHP

Tags: php

RESULT IS :

price is5,850.00Euros 
and I need this
price is 5,850.00 Euros

```
<?
$quantity = 25;
$price = 195;
$tax = .20;

$quite = $quantity * $price;
$quite = $quite + ($quite * $tax);
$quite = number_format($quite, 2);

echo 'price is' , $quite , 'Euros';


?>
```

Thanks

Comment: so put a space inside the strings where you need them.... surely that's not difficult to work out??

Comment: Now, no its not, will be better delete this question now? I mean for spam?

Comment: no, don't worry about it. I don't think you can delete a question that has answers on it. Just accept one of the answers and leave it at that.  :)

Comment: Thaank you, I use stackoverflow for a first time, Also Im beginer in PHP, thanks for patience :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
echo 'price is ' , $quite , ' Euros';
```

or even:

```
echo "price is $quite Euros";
```

For details on the latter syntax, see the ["Variable parsing" section in the PHP manual on Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

(Ps. Shouldn't that be `$quote` instead of `$quite`?)

Comment: thank you very much. Maybe should, this quite I mean The total amount. Thank for link i Will visit this site! :)

Comment: will be better delete this question now? I mean for spam?

Comment: It's not really spam, or I wouldn't have answered it. It's not the greatest question in the world (since I'm sure you could've figured out the answer by yourself in a few minutes), but who knows, maybe someone else will have the same problem some day and find it on Google. Stranger things have happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo 'price is ' , $quite , ' Euros';
```